# change python executable to the one installed by brew on mac for virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, homebrew

My Mac comes installed with python 2.7.2 in /usr/bin. Yet for our project I need to use python 2.7.6. So I did a brew install python.

Now python 2.7.6 is installed in /usr/local/bin/python. Yet when I create a new virtualenv it still creates one with the 2.7.2 python version installed in /usr/bin.

How can I tell virtualenv to create a virtual environment with the 2.7.6 version?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this flag when creating the env:

```
 $ virtualenv --help
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  ...
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                        The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                        --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                        to create the new environment.  The default is the
                        interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
                        (/usr/bin/python)
```